# Changing code of Xcode through Jenkins shell script

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, build, jenkins

I am working on an iPhone application, it has a UIWebview that loads an url. When i make changes in code i commit it in Github and then every night Jenkins does the build and deploy it on the server.

My problem is, i want to change the url of UIWebview through Jenkins shell script. So it should make a build with development url and one with production url. I think i have to create two different jobs but how do i tell the Jenkins job that which url it should build for.

Appreciate your help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thought is to use a command line define in the compile step `-DmyURL='@"$(MYURL)"'` and then use a paramarerized build which takes the URL as a build-time parameter and then set that environment variable from there (which is what the parameterized build is for).

Then, in your code, refer to the URL from the definition.

```
#ifndef myURL
    #define myURL @"http://dev.foo.com"
#endif
```

Then you just use myURL in place of the constant.

Another way to do this would be to just have a simple value defined in the compile step which would be a Boolean and then you could put both URLs in code, but the first solution would allow dynamic determination of the URL at compile time.

To use a bool-style mechanism, just set `-DUSE_PROD_URL=$(USE_PROD)` and then in the code:

```
#if USE_PROD_URL
    URL=@"http://prod.url.com"
#else
    URL=@"http://dev.uel.com"
#endif
```

Comment: in the bool-style example, if I want to set TRUE to the USE_PROD_URL, I have to use `-DUSE_PROD_URL=$(YES)`? Thanks!

Comment: @RenatoLochetti That's true if you aren't using a variable in the environment to determine how you want the switch to be thrown.   If you set it to `$(YES)`, then the compile line isn't dynamic.   By setting it to `$(USE_PROD)` and then setting `USE_PROD` in the environment determines which way the script runs.   This would allow the build environment to be agnostic to what kind of build is being created and you can control it in Jenkins by defining `USE_PROD` on a per-build basis, which was what I was aiming for here.   Think a production build for upload and the non-prod for test.